# Multiple commands with parameter: How to use logical or?

Tags: bash, shell-script

we are given two commands

```
    sbatch -J $jobname -N 1 --array [1-10:1] \
         script.sh param1 param2 param3 \
         param4 param5 param6; 
    qsub -N $jobname -t 1-10:1 \ 
         script.sh param1 param2 param3 \
         param4 param5 param6;
```

I would like to use an logical or for executing the second command if the first command fails.

I have already tried:

```
{ sbatch ... ; } || \
{ qsub ... ; }
```

Edit: To be a bit more concrete.

There are two cluster. On the first one SLURM is running and on the second SGE. I would like to use the same scripts for SLURM and SGE.
Therefore I have attempt to solve this task by using a logical or: if first command fails (because command unknown since system not exists) then execute second command.

Execution of

```
    sbatch -J $jobname -N 1 --array [1-10:1] \
         script.sh param1 param2 param3 \
         param4 param5 param6; ||
    qsub -N $jobname -t 1-10:1 \ 
         script.sh param1 param2 param3 \
         param4 param5 param6;
```

yields

```
syntax error near unexpected token `||'
```

Execution of

```
{ sbatch ... ; } || 
{ qsub ... ; }
```

yields

```
sbatch: command not found
Your job-array 9982202.1-10:1
```

Comment: And ... what happened when you tried that? Also: these seem to be using some batch processing system. If that's the case, what does "if the first command fails" mean? If `sbatch` itself failed? If `script.sh` failed? There's also the question of "when"

Comment: Try to remove the semicolon `;` before the `||` operation.

Comment: And I assume you're using bash?

Comment: Yes bash @aviro. Executing ```sbatch ... || qsub ... ``` yields ```sbatch: command not found```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and, in effect, more elegant to first check the system you run on, and then run the respective command?

Comment: And if you run just the `sbatch` command on a single line with the subsequest "or" and "qsub" part, does it work?

Comment: No. I deleted all ```\``` as well as all semicolons and run the command on a single line then the same error occurs again: ```sbatch ... || qsub ... ``` -> ```sbatch: command not found``` @aviro

Comment: Try the following and tell me what happens: `sbatch || echo BAD`

Comment: Leads to ```sbatch: command not found
BAD``` @aviro

Answer (score 2):

Executing `qsub` depending on the exit status of `sbatch` is done as you show, with `||` between the two commands:

```bsh
sbatch -J "$jobname" -N 1 --array '[1-10:1]' \
        script.sh param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6 ||
qsub -N "$jobname" -t '1-10:1' \
        script.sh param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6
```

However, this would *not* make `qsub` depend on the exit status of the script `script.sh` that `sbatch` is running.

To make `sbatch` terminate with the same exit status as you script `script.sh`, you will have to use `sbatch` with its `-W` or `--wait` option:

> `-W`, `--wait`
> Do not exit until the submitted job terminates. The exit code of the `sbatch` command will be the same as the exit code of the submitted job. If the job terminated due to a signal rather than a normal exit, the exit code will be set to 1. In the case of a job array, the exit code recorded will be the highest value for any task in the job array.

I.e.,

```bsh
sbatch -W -J "$jobname" -N 1 --array '[1-10:1]' \
        script.sh param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6 ||
qsub -N "$jobname" -t '1-10:1' \
        script.sh param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6
```

---

If all you want to do is to execute the `sbatch` command if that command is available, otherwise run the `qsub` command, then you could use

```bsh
if command -v sbatch >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    sbatch -J "$jobname" -N 1 --array '[1-10:1]' \
            script.sh param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6
else
    qsub -N "$jobname" -t '1-10:1' \
            script.sh param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6
fi
```

This tests with the shells built-in `command` utility whether `sbatch` may be found.  If the test is successful, `sbatch` is executed, otherwise `qsub` is attempted.

Comment: I extended my description. Sorry for being undetailed. Since qsub or sbatch does not exist on both custers one command must fail. Therefore -W should be not necessary, since script.sh can be executed in at most one case. That is, when the command is not failing. Unfortunately, your first proposal is also not working and yields: syntax error near unexpected token `||'. Edit: I see that you added quotes to "$jobname" etc. Is this really necessary? Will it make a difference?

Comment: @GeoRie It's unclear how you are executing the commands that you show. An ordinary shell would definitely not complain with a syntax error.

Comment: @GeoRie Are you adding a semicolon after the first command? If so, *don't*. You can terminate a command with a semicolon, a `&`, `&&`, `|`, or `||`, but not more than one of them. (You can also use a newline, which acts like a semicolon in most cases.) If you use `command1; || command2` the shell will complain because there's no valid command between the `;` and the `||`.

Comment: @GeoRie The quoting is to avoid having the shell split the value of the variable into separate words. You don't show what `$jobname` is, so I must assume that it could be a multi-word string, potentially containing file globbing characters.

Comment: Yes you are right @they. My mistake. The syntax error was caused by the semicolon at the end. However, deleting all semicolons leads to ```sbatch: command not found```

Comment: @GeoRie Yes, see the added bits to my answer.  I can't but assume that you are testing the _exact_ code I'm giving you, with no extra semicolons or other things added.

Comment: For sue using an if statement will solve this problem. However, it leads to more code and that is what I aim to prevent. Therefore I prefer to use a logical or.

Comment: @GeoRie You are free to do that too if you wish. Note however that if `sbatch` exists but fails to run or terminates with an error for whatever reason, `qsub` would be attempted, if you use an OR-list. The best would be if you used two separate submission scripts, one for each system, instead of trying to make a universal script that may introduce bugs.

Comment: This is true. But it does not matter since the consequence using locigal or would only be one additional line in the error logfile containing ```qsub: command not found```.

Comment: @GeoRie Right, in that case I don't really see what your issue is. You could just use the first piece of code in my answer.